# What is the best way to pass another model instance back from a separate controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models Users and Reports. A User has many Reports. For Reports, I currently have "user_id" as an int in my schema.

My reports_controller has an index method that returns all the Reports, but it only returns the user_id.

What is the best way to get the actual User instance included?

reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  
  def index
    reports = Report.all

    render json: {
      reports: reports
    }
  end

  def create
    report = Report.create!(
      user_id: params["report"]["user_id"],
      rep_type: params["report"]["rep_type"],
      rep_count: params["report"]["rep_count"]
    )

    if report
      render json: { 
        status: :created,
        report: report
      }
    else
      render json: { status: 500 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please define how you would this structured and/or look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

You can query for your user in the index action.

```rb
  def index
    reports = Report.all
    @user = User.find_by(id: params["report"]["user_id"])

    render json: {
      reports: reports
    }
  end
```

Also if your relationship is defined correctly you and you only have one Report you should be able to access `user_ids` when querying Report model.